# Shadowing functions of C stdlib/stdio

Tags: c++, file-io, stdio, std, shadowing

I am writing a game and for now i was able to implement a *filesystem* via `sqlite` with a class and its methods. To make life more easy i have planned to write some functions like `fopen`,`fclose`,`fread`,`rename`, etc. to be able to shadow the base functions and to direct my calls to my filesystem rather than to the original one. For the first three function everything worked fine for me with these prototypes:

> `File *fopen(String _Filename, String _Mode); // i have my own optimized File struct`
>
> `void fclose(File *_File);`
>
> `size_t fread(String *_DstBuf, size_t _ElementSize, size_t _Count, File *_File);`

This worked fine as i am either returning another struct or the parameters except a `File*` and not a `FILE*`, however the rename function seems to be a bit trickier!

> `int rename(String _OldFilename, String _NewFilename);`

This is nearly the same prototype. except that i use `std::string` (typedef'ed `String`) than `const char*`! Any idea how i could convince my compiler either to use my function or to ignore the stdio-one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And what is the reason that you cannot simply use your own functions by any other name?

If the whole conflict is with overload resolution, you should simply just shadow the *actual* prototypes; You can make them forwards to your own functions.

However, I recommend against the general approach here: even with that 'fix' in place you will at the very best have include ordering issues, and possibly even duplicate link symbols.

If your functions don't do the same, make them use another name. Since you are using c++, you could do this vile trick (otherwise ill-advised) in MyFsFunctions.h:

```
namespace MyFsFunctions 
{
     // prototypes for fopen, fclose, fwrite, fread etc
}

using namespace MyFsFunctions;
// or:
using MyFsFunctions::fopen;
using MyFsFunctions::fclose;
using MyFsFunctions::fread;
using MyFsFunctions::fwrite; // etc...
```

I'm pretty sure you will still want (need) to shadow the exact function prototypes (or the compiler may still complain about ambiguous identifiers references).

Other hints:

1. use a fuse file system driver (on Linux/UNIX/MacOS; might be overkill, but implementing it seems a lot more robust and may even simpler than what you do here).
2. there is always C macros (-10 points for evil)
3. gnu linker has options that let's you 'replace' link symbols - mainly for debugging purposes, but you can leverage those here

Comment: The vile namespace trick worked fine for the first prototypes, however i have the problem with `rename` as the compiler is not able to decide whether my params are `const char*` or `String`s! Trying to call `rename(String("/dev/null"), String("/dev/less"));` solved the conflict, however it is not that good to call the `String` constructor everytime i pass an argument.

Comment: Could you try explicitely adding `using MyFsFunctions::rename;` in addition to/instead of `using namespace MyFsFunctions;`?

Comment: Didn't work! However a `#define rename MyFsFunctions::rename` could solve the problem, but this is C++ and i don't like macros like in C >.< // EDIT: Your second solution worked, BUT the line needs to be entered INTO the function and not into the sourcefile...

Comment: I'm sure you can do the using in a class namespace to. I'm not sure whether that is lexically scoped or augments the actual class namespace. I'm afraid that it is lexically scoped, so you'd need to repeat it if you have implementations outside the class declaration (otherwise, you can benefit from the ODR and have 'automatic' usings from the class definition).

Comment: For now i am bound to write the mentioned prologue like this
`void foo() { using MyFsFunctions::rename; rename(...); }`

Comment: My $0.05: Just name the function `renameex(...)` (perhaps `fopenex`, `fcloseex`); It will make it clear to anyone what is actually happening. I wouldn't like working with a codebase where `printf` and `floor` could be overridden, personnally. _This was my 1st line as well :)_

Comment: I will try more things - but in the end i think i am goind to `ex` all these functions :-) - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

How about implementing a `rename` with the standard signature that all it will do would be calling your `String`ed version?

Doesn't sound complicated to me. Something like this:

```
int rename(const char *charOld, const char *charNew)
{
    std::string stdOld(charOld);
    std::string stdNew(charNew);
    return rename(stdOld, stdNew);
}
```

Comment: @littleadv and @vines - didn't work! the compiler just ignored it!

Comment: @littleadv - can you correct your code so that i am able to copy&paste it?

Comment: @littleadv - i thought you have meant something else, i have tried this way already with no success at all! @sehe 's way with namespaces seems to be the best workaround, however i must write a *prologue* mentioning all methods i am goind to use. Maybe we can optimize this part!

Comment: If you inline it, the already compiled library code will not see it! You have to have **exactly** the same signature as the function you are replacing.

Comment: @Chris - using a separate namespace is indeed a better solution, unless you want external libraries to be diverted to your code, you should us it.